# Exception handling of excel macro and xlwings

Tags: xlwings

```
import xlwings as xw
def ImportAndRun():
    wb =xw.Book(r'filepath.xlsm')
    wb.sheets['Data'].range['OptionID'].value = 10079
    wb.macro('getResults')
```

> everything till the macro call runs fine. The issue is that the macro itself has a bug and a stand alone vba call errs out in the macro
>   where as xlwings just exits with out flagging anything and runs to the
>   next line. How do I catch/handle exceptions thrown by vba with xlwings?

Answer (score 0):

This is an uncomfortable situation. Rather than adopting an oblique route, would you be in a position to fix that VBA macro?

If you can't:

1. Assuming the macro does err out in VBA, then I would make a wrapper in VBA, catch the error (On Error goto Err_...) and see if I can fix it from there.
2. It could even be that you could bypass this macro and do what you need with xlwings?

To answer your question, we would need to know more about what your macro is supposed to do and what it is doing wrong.